# How to implement Exoplayer 2.11.1 in android?

Tags: android, exoplayer, audio-player, android-music-player, exoplayer2.x

i am trying to implement [exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) this is my `exoplayer` version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.1'
```

i am creating a music player app and i don't know anything about `exoplayer` i am trying to implement `exoplayer` from last 2 days but it's not working. i couldn't understand anything in the official documentation .

i find many example and tutorial but it's all about playing video using `exoplayer`. many example's are using deprecated methods.

I am trying to implement using this [tutorial](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-exoplayer-to-play-video-and-audio-in-android-like-a-pro) but many of methods are deprecated so it's not working
EX.

```
simpleExoplayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
            DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
            DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory),
            DefaultLoadControl()
        )
```

can anyone suggest me where to start or how do i build music streaming app using latest version of  `exoplayer`.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the new update, you can create a simple player instance using `SimpleExoPlayer.Builder`:

```
simpleExoplayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
```

You can also supply the `Builder` with different arguments. See https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.Builder.html

You can use this simple custom class I created to help you get started.

```
class ExoPlayerHelper(
    private val playerView: PlayerView,
    onError: (ExoPlaybackException) -> Unit,
    onPlayerBuffer: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {

    private var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null
    private var mediaSource: ProgressiveMediaSource? = null

    private val playerListener = object : Player.EventListener {
        override fun onPlayerError(error: ExoPlaybackException) {
            super.onPlayerError(error)
            onError(error)
        }

        override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
            super.onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady, playbackState)
            onPlayerBuffer(playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING)
        }
    }

    fun initializePlayer(url: String) {
        exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(playerView.context).build()
        exoPlayer!!.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
        exoPlayer!!.addListener(playerListener)

        playerView.player = exoPlayer

        val userAgent =
            Util.getUserAgent(playerView.context, playerView.context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource
            .Factory(
                DefaultDataSourceFactory(playerView.context, userAgent),
                DefaultExtractorsFactory()
            )
            .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url))

        exoPlayer!!.prepare(mediaSource!!, true, false)
        exoPlayer!!.playWhenReady = true
    }

    private fun killPlayer() {
        if (exoPlayer != null) {
            exoPlayer!!.release()
            exoPlayer = null
            mediaSource = null
            playerView.player = null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of language the sample is written with? is it dart or kotlin?

Comment: @Behrouz.M it's kotlin

Answer (score 5):

I also faced this problem and this my solution

**[Declaration](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.Builder.html)**

```
private val exoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer by lazy { SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()}
```

**Play Song**

```
private fun prepareExoPlayerFromURL(url: String) {
        val dataSourceFactory =
            DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)), null)
        val extractorsFactory = DefaultExtractorsFactory()
//        val audioSource = ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null)

        val concateMediaSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource()

        // to play from song list
        for (i in mSongList) {      // song list song arraylist
            val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource
                .Factory(
                    DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, dataSourceFactory),
                    DefaultExtractorsFactory()
                )
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(i.musicFile)/*Uri.parse(i.uri)*/)
            concateMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource)
        }

        // to play single song
       /* val audioSource = ProgressiveMediaSource
            .Factory(
                DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, dataSourceFactory),
                DefaultExtractorsFactory()
            )
            .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url))*/

        exoPlayer.prepare(concateMediaSource/*audioSource*/)
        exoPlayer.seekToDefaultPosition(songPosition)
        exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true

        setNotification()
    }
```

to set **listener** of player and notification

```
private fun setListoner() {
        exoPlayer.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                when (playbackState) {
                    Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> Log.e(TAG,"STATE_BUFFERING")
                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> Log.e(TAG,"STATE_ENDED")
                    Player.STATE_IDLE -> Log.e(TAG,"STATE_IDLE")
                    Player.STATE_READY ->{
                        if (playWhenReady) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "PlaybackStatus.PLAYING")
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "PlaybackStatus.PAUSED")
                        }
                    }
                    else -> Log.e(TAG,"PlaybackStatus.IDLE")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

to **Kill player**

```
 private fun onDestroy() {
        if (exoPlayer != null) {
            exoPlayer.release()
            exoPlayer = null
            mediaSource = null
        }
    }
```

for more detail you can see [official documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html)

The [Universal Music Player](https://github.com/android/uamp) uses ExoPlayer for local audio playback.

[Building feature-rich media apps with ExoPlayer (Google I/O '18)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svdq1BWl4r8)

Comment: thanks, it's working for me, and thanks for extra information and links.

Answer (score 4):

For Java Guys (Long Live Java)

**In Activity**

```
private PlayerView epPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.design_reference);
```

**The Public Function**

```
public static void runExoPlayer(PlayerView epPlayerView,
                                String url,
                                Context context) {

    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);

    SimpleExoPlayer  exoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
    epPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);

    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri);
    exoPlayer.clearMediaItems();
    exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    exoPlayer.prepare();
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

}
```

**Build Gradle**

```
   // Exo Media Player
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.15.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.15.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.15.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.15.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.15.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.15.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Until 2.15.0 version, you can create SimpleExoPlayer instance as the following :

```
SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory)
            .build()
```

With the 2.16.0 version, SimpleExoPlayer is deprecated, you should use ExoPlayer instance instead. You can create it as the following :

```
ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory)
            .build()
```

https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.Builder.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Call this method :

   ```
   private void initializePlayer() {
            FloatingWidgetService.hidePipPlayer();

            binding.videoOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            liveTvexoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
            binding.playerView.setPlayer(liveTvexoPlayer);
            binding.playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT);
            binding.playerView.setUseController(true);

            liveTvexoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            liveTvexoPlayer.seekTo(0);
            appManageInterface.setLiveTvVideo(playBackUrl, "getReady", 0);
            Prefs.getPrefInstance().setValue(context, Const.VIDEO_URL, playBackUrl);

            imgViewChangeScreenOrientation = binding.playerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_icon);
            imgViewChangeScreenOrientation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    liveTvexoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                    liveTvexoPlayer.release();
                    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, FloatingWidgetService.class);
                    serviceIntent.putExtra("videoUri", playBackUrl);
                    serviceIntent.putExtra("isfrom", "livetv");
    //                serviceIntent.putExtra("videoUri", "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/SubaruOutbackOnStreetAndDirt.mp4");
                    getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
                }
            });

            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .setContentType(C.CONTENT_TYPE_MOVIE)
                    .build();
            if (liveTvexoPlayer.getAudioComponent() != null)
                liveTvexoPlayer.getAudioComponent().setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, true);
            try {
                if (!playBackUrl.equals("")) {
                    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));
                    MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(playBackUrl));
                    liveTvexoPlayer.prepare(videoSource, true, true);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            liveTvexoPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                    switch (error.type) {
                        case TYPE_SOURCE:
                            binding.videoOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                        case TYPE_RENDERER:
                        case TYPE_UNEXPECTED:
                            liveTvexoPlayer.retry();
                            break;
                        case TYPE_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        case TYPE_REMOTE:
                            AppUtil.show_Snackbar(context, binding.playerView, error.getMessage(), true);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
   ```
2. Manage exoplayer with below method:

   ```
       @Override
       public void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
           mTracker.setScreenName("Screen - " + "Live Tv");
           mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
           binding.playerView.onResume();
           if (liveTvexoPlayer != null)
               liveTvexoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
       }

       @Override
       public void onStart() {
           super.onStart();
           binding.playerView.onResume();
           if (liveTvexoPlayer != null)
               liveTvexoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
       }

       @Override
       public void onPause() {
           binding.playerView.onPause();
           if (liveTvexoPlayer != null) {
               liveTvexoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
           }
           super.onPause();
       }

       @Override
       public void onStop() {
           binding.playerView.onPause();
           if (liveTvexoPlayer != null)
               liveTvexoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
           super.onStop();
       }

       @Override
       public void onDestroy() {
           binding.playerView.onPause();
           if (liveTvexoPlayer != null) {
               liveTvexoPlayer.release();
               liveTvexoPlayer = null;
           }
           super.onDestroy();
       }
   ```