# ExoPlayer initialize player deprecated

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

I'm currently working with the latest `ExoPlayer` update and I'm getting calls that it is deprecated, could someone help me?

```
private fun initializePlayer () {

    if (simpleExoPlayer == null) {
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(this)
        val loadControl = DefaultLoadControl()
        simpleExoPlayer = E̶x̶o̶P̶l̶a̶y̶e̶r̶F̶a̶c̶t̶o̶r̶y̶.̶n̶e̶w̶S̶i̶m̶p̶l̶e̶I̶n̶s̶t̶a̶n̶c̶e̶(this, trackSelector, loadControl)
    }
}
```

Comment: the docs just say you should use ``SimpleExoPlayer.Builder`` or ``ExoPlayer.Builder`` instead of that Factory: https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayerFactory.html

Comment: Please see here for Oct 2021 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69626390/3904109

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's worked. You should use this version:

`implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.2'`

```
exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = true
        binding.playerView.player = exoPlayer
        val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
        val mediaItem =
            MediaItem.fromUri(URL)
        val mediaSource =
            HlsMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem)
        exoPlayer?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        exoPlayer?.seekTo(playbackPosition)
        exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
        exoPlayer?.prepare()
```

Answer (score 9):

**Setting Up Exoplayer version(2.11.8) :

Sep 2020 Update:**

```
//Setting Up Exoplayer
private void SetupPlayer(){
        SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
// Create a data source factory.
        dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this
                        , getApplicationInfo().loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString()));
// Passing Load Control
        loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
                .setBufferDurationsMs(25000, 50000, 1500, 2000).createDefaultLoadControl();

        @DefaultRenderersFactory.ExtensionRendererMode int extensionRendererMode = DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER;

        renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(this) .setExtensionRendererMode(extensionRendererMode);

// Create a progressive media source pointing to a stream uri.
         mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url_to_stream));
// Create a player instance.
        simpleExoPlayer =  new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this,renderersFactory).setLoadControl(loadControl).build();
// Prepare the player with the media source.
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource, true, true);
}
```

Comment: any further information on this? please add source also for read full source . Thanks