# Unable to stream Audio file through exoplayer in latest version Android

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using `exoplayer` to stream my Audio files from Firebase storage to my app. I used `Media player` earlier which was so slow. So I changed to `exoplayer` and its version was 2.8.4 at that time.

Here's the Code i used to stream Audio:

```
SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
private void SetupPlayer(){
    DefaultRenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(this,
            null,DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_OFF);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
            .setAllocator(new DefaultAllocator(true, 16))
            .setBufferDurationsMs(MIN_BUFFER_DURATION,
                    MAX_BUFFER_DURATION,
                    MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER,
                    MIN_PLAYBACK_RESUME_BUFFER)
            .setTargetBufferBytes(-1)
            .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(true).createDefaultLoadControl();
    simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(renderersFactory,trackSelector,loadControl);
    String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "Play Audio");
    ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(audio_url),new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, userAgent),
            new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),null,null);

    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
}
```

It worked great. But now `exoplayer` has updated its version to `2.11.8`. In this version, `ExtractorMediaSource`, `DefaultRenderersFactory`, `DefaultTrackSelector`, `ExoPlayerFactory` are deprecated.

So I changed my code for the recent version.

Here's the Code:

```
    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
    private void SetupPlayer(){
       // Create a data source factory.
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this
                        , "app-name"));
// Create a progressive media source pointing to a stream uri.
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(audio_url));
// Create a player instance.
        simpleExoPlayer =  new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
// Prepare the player with the media source.
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    }
```

Now it is showing error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.SlidingPercentile.<clinit>(SlidingPercentile.java:38)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter.<init>(DefaultBandwidthMeter.java:276)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter.<init>(DefaultBandwidthMeter.java:48)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter$Builder.build(DefaultBandwidthMeter.java:190)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter.getSingletonInstance(DefaultBandwidthMeter.java:229)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer$Builder.<init>(SimpleExoPlayer.java:144)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer$Builder.<init>(SimpleExoPlayer.java:126)
        at com.paulstevenme.jeevaoli.StoryAudioActivity.SetupPlayer(StoryAudioActivity.java:323)
        at com.paulstevenme.jeevaoli.StoryAudioActivity.onCreate(StoryAudioActivity.java:125)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

I searched `Stack overflow`. But everyone answers are deprecated ones. So I don't know how to fix it. Please help me with some solutions.

Comment: But I am passing audio url in media source

Comment: @ blackapps, Now it was showing  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` error. I Updated the Question

Comment: Well which method is not found? The logs tell you. Please post the log in a code block to keep the lines.

Comment: @blackapps, I updated the log in Question

Comment: Some method is missing. Which one exactly. Maybe you need another version of some library. Catch the exception for now .

Comment: Please see here for Oct 2021 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69626390/3904109

Answer (score 1):

Found the Answer. I just missed adding `compile options` in `build gradle.` After Adding, it worked.

```
compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```