# After upgrading ExoPlayer from 2.11.8 to 2.12.1 and replacing deprecated components I can't play any video

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I've recently upgraded `com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core` from version 2.11.8 to version 2.12.1.
Some components are deprecated by version 2.12.1 in the following code snippet.

```
        cacheEvictor = LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(CACHE_SIZE_MAX)
        databaseProvider = ExoDatabaseProvider(context)
        cache = SimpleCache(File(context.cacheDir, CACHE_DIR),
                cacheEvictor, databaseProvider)
        upstreamFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, USER_AGENT)
        // CacheDataSourceFactory class is deprecated
        cacheFactory = CacheDataSourceFactory(cache, upstreamFactory,
                CacheDataSource.FLAG_BLOCK_ON_CACHE or
                        CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR)
        mediaSourceFactory = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheFactory)
        [...]
        val url: Uri
        val player: SimpleExoPlayer
        [...]
        // createMediaSource method is deprecated
        val mediaSource = mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(uri)
        // prepare method is deprecated
        player.prepare(mediaSource, true, true)
```

Thus I replaced the deprecated components by the newest ones.

```
        cacheEvictor = LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(CACHE_SIZE_MAX)
        databaseProvider = ExoDatabaseProvider(context)
        cache = SimpleCache(File(context.cacheDir, CACHE_DIR),
                cacheEvictor, databaseProvider)
        upstreamFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, USER_AGENT)
        cacheFactory = CacheDataSource.Factory().apply {
              setCache(this@VideoPlayer.cache)
              setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(upstreamFactory)
              setFlags(CacheDataSource.FLAG_BLOCK_ON_CACHE or                  
                    CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR)
        }
        mediaSourceFactory = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheFactory)
        [...]
        val url: Uri
        val player: SimpleExoPlayer
        [...]
        val mediaItem =  MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
        val mediaSource = mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(mediaItem)
        player.setMediaSource(mediaSource, true)
        // The following missed
        player.prepare(mediaSource)
```

After the updates, the player was black and I could not play any video (nothing usefull in Logcat).
I've returned to the deprecated components (still with version 2.12.1) and now I can play every video.

I think I messed up something when in replacing the deprecated components.
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Please see here for Oct 2021 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69626390/3904109

Answer (score 2):

I've just fixed the code in the answer: I had forgotten the last `player.prepare()`.
Now it works fine.